# Why does Spring not see my @Resource annotated object after Obfuscation?

Tags: java, spring, obfuscation

I have inherited an application that is written using Spring 3.2. The application works absolutely fine when built when it is not obfuscated. Once obfuscated (using ProGuard) I get the following exception in my logs.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailStoreFactoryImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [de.aeromaritime.messaging.roudistsrv.data.RdsDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(mappedName=, shareable=true, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, lookup=, authenticationType=CONTAINER)}
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at de.aeromaritime.messaging.roudistsrv.ServiceMain.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain.executeMain(WrapperJVMMain.java:53)
at org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain.main(WrapperJVMMain.java:36)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [de.aeromaritime.messaging.roudistsrv.data.RdsDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(mappedName=, shareable=true, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, lookup=, authenticationType=CONTAINER)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:438)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:550)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
... 19 more
```

The thing is that the RdsDAO object is never made into a bean in the config.xml. This means it must be instanced by some other part of Spring. So I looked around and found that the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` apparently loads objects that annotated with <s>@Resource</s>`@Repository`. So I checked the RdsDAO object and sure enough it has the correct annotation to be read.

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, readOnly = true)
 @Repository
 public class RdsDAO implements Serializable
 { ...
 }
```

Then I looked into the config.xml and find

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
   xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"

   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
      http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd 

<!-- ### enable annotations -->
<context:annotation-config/>
<!-- ### scan for annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="de.aeromaritime.messaging.roudistsrv"/>
<!-- ### AOP support -->  
<!-- force use CGLIB to proxy classes even if there is an interface -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

<context:spring-configured/>

<!-- Exception translation bean post processor -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<!-- ### Create the PlatformTransactionManager -->

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
  </property>
</bean>

<!-- ### TX enable transaction annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

So the bean for `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` is there and should be working (as it does when the application is not obfuscated).

Finally I looked at the code for my `mailStoreFactoryImpl` bean which has the RdsDAO as a field like this:

```
public final class MailStoreFactoryImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements
    ICMailStoreFactory, Serializable
{
    @Resource
    private RdsDAO rdsDAO;
  ...
}
```

Finally just to check, I decompiled my Jar file and looked at both the RdsDAO class, and MailStoreFactoryImpl class and found that they still have the same naming and contain the same fields, so basically Obfuscating didn't do anything to either of these classes. I'm beating my head on the desk trying to understand what Obfuscated did to break this application, but I'm at a loss. If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear from you.

[UPDATE]
I'm adding below the contents of my library.pro file:

```
#
# This ProGuard configuration file illustrates how to process a program
# library, such that it remains usable as a library.
# Usage:
#     java -jar proguard.jar @library.pro
#

# Specify the input jars, output jars, and library jars.
# In this case, the input jar is the program library that we want to process.

-injars      dist/ASYM_RDS-unobfuscated.jar
-outjars     dist/ASYM_RDS.jar

-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars  dist/lib

# Save the obfuscation mapping to a file, so we can de-obfuscate any stack
# traces later on. Keep a fixed source file attribute and all line number
# tables to get line numbers in the stack traces.
# You can comment this out if you're not interested in stack traces.

-printmapping out.map
#-keepparameternames
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
#-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
#                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,EnclosingMethod

# Preserve all annotations.

-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Preserve all public classes, and their public and protected fields and
# methods.

-keep public class * {
#    public protected *;
    public *;
}

# Preserve all .class method names.

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

# Preserve all public applications.

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration
# classes.

-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
# You can comment this out if your library doesn't use serialization.
# If your code contains serializable classes that have to be backward
# compatible, please refer to the manual.

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

#Added as per answer to SO question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25419369
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javax.annotation.Resource *;
}


# Your library may contain more items that need to be preserved; 
# typically classes that are dynamically created using Class.forName:

# -keep public class mypackage.MyClass
# -keep public interface mypackage.MyInterface
# -keep public class * implements mypackage.MyInterface

-ignorewarnings
-dontoptimize
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in ProGuard but I onced looked at another post giving in its answer a working configuration : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393590/proguard-in-a-maven-spring-3-big-web-application . Hope it can help ...

Comment: It didn't help, but thanks. It did get me thinking that maybe I'm looking at this from the wrong end. I'm currently trying some ProGuard stuff to see if I see any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting -keepclassmembers to @javax.annotation.Resource?

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javax.annotation.Resource *;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you might have to wire your context together by name, since your class names are likely getting mangled. Add @Bean("somename") to the classes and update the fields to @Resource("somename") so they match.

Comment: Just tried it Ted, and it didn't work. I've included the contents of my library.pro file. You can see where I added your answer but as I said the exception is still the same.

Comment: Updated answer with something else to try.

Comment: The problem I'm seeing here is that the bean that is causing the problem isn't called in the context at all. It is loaded using the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` bean in the context. However, maybe by adding the name to the `@Resource` would work. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Nope that's not working. I've added a name to the `@Repository` to force a bean name, but it is still ignored. Any attempt to add a name parameter to the `@Resource` ends up throwing a JNDI exception.

Comment: I'm wondering if <context:component-scan base-package="de.aeromaritime.messaging.roudistsrv"/> is not finding classes.  Did the code you decompiled have a different package name?

Comment: Nope, the packages weren't obfuscated. So that shouldn't be the problem.